# HTML DOM traversal using Treewalker in VBA

Tags: html, internet-explorer, excel, vba

If I create an IE application object in VBA, I can download webpages and also use the `document` property to call functions like `getElementById`. However, I wanted DOM traversal capabilities desperately.

The documentation defines a `treeWalker` object which looks very promising but I am just not able to make `createTreeWalker` work. I am getting an `object required` error at the function call to `createTreeWalker`. Has anybody used this method or can somebody point me to an example where `treeWalker` has been used through VBA?

Comment: Can't help with TreeWalker, but I'll tell you that I had a heck of a time trying to traverse an HTML DOM until I found out that I needed to reference `Document.frame.Document.control` rather than `Document.frame.control`. This was a while ago, and employer-proprietary....

Comment: If the webpages concerned are well-formed XHTML then you could download them using the `XMLHTTP60` object instead - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757026%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that TreeWalker has not been implemented until at least IE9 (which my employer does not provide unfortunately). However, I still managed DOM traversal using the following properties:

```
.childNodes(x) 'x begins at 0
.parentNode
.nextSibling
.innerHTML
```

These properties apply to almost any node which `getElementById()` might throw up and these are implemented in earleir IE versions as well.